# How to follow up on interview process that is dragging out

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I am currently contract employed and looking for a full-time position. I applied to a dream job in March through a corporate job portal, not really expecting anything, and heard back from their in-house recruiter a month later. Nearly five months later, there's not been a final decision. I've had multiple phone interviews and last month completed a skills test for them. If it hadn't been so long (typically 3-4 weeks) between each contact, I'd write it off at this point. But every time I'd made my peace with the fact they'd moved on, I'd get another call or email.

Today I received a job offer that, while not a dream job, is stable and I like the team. I feel like I need to check in with the other job before I actually accept though. I'm conflicted about the best way to go about this. I know I could accept this offer and potentially take the dream job down the line, but I'd like to make this decision with as much information in hand as possible. Should I just email a quick note, checking in on their process? Is it too pushy/heavy-handed to mention I'm considering another offer? I'd love any suggestions on specific languages.

Comment: Think about it from their perspective, if you were trying to hire someone and one of the people at the top of your list received another offer, would you want to know? I would think so. So assume you are at the top of their list. A simple phone call or email saying you have received an offer at another company and will be making a decision in the next few weeks makes sense. That said, wow, 5 months. It may be the dream job, but is it the dream company?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you should reach out to the dream job.  You need to find out if your application is still being considered, and to let them know that you have received another job offer so depending on how long a decision makes you may no longer be available.

Even something as simple as:

Dear (Gender neutral pronoun) HR person
When we last spoke you indicated that the super position is still open, and the hiring process ongoing.  Is there any update on when you expect to fill the role?  I recently received a full time offer for another position and wanted to find out about super position before I made any decision.

Thank you -
- Sadielady

They will either get back to you right away to let you know the status of super position, or not.  If they do not get back to you within a reasonable amount of time, I would take the other job.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it too pushy/heavy-handed to mention I'm considering another offer?

**Do exactly this!**

This is less about "checking" with them and more about "putting pressure on" them. If they are still considering your candidacy expect them to move much faster now :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, all. I reached out and let them know I had another opportunity developing quickly. Got an email and a call within a few hours that I'm still very much in the running, and they're bringing me out for visit. Now I'm stressed about how to handle the other offer, but glad to know I'm still a candidate.